# URL Alias for Contrloler/Method in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: url, alias, codeigniter-4

In CodeIgniter 3 I could do this in the **Config/Routes.php** file:
`$routes->get('Net_Price', 'SomeController::SomeNonIndexMethod');`
'Net_Price' is an alias (for the lack of a better term).  And the URL to access this Controller/Method was:
[www.example.com/Net_Price](http://www.example.com/Net_Price) (I could even use capital letters in the alias.)

I want to do exactly this - in CodeIgniter 4.  Is it possible?

The closest I've gotten is if I put the following route into **Config/Routes.php** (of CI4).
`$routes->match(['get', 'post'], 'SomeController/SomeNonIndexMethod', 'SomeController::SomeNonIndexMethod', ['as' => 'Net_Price']);`
Then I can do `redirect()->route('Net_Price')` (not `redirect()->**to**('Net_Price')` what does redirect()->**to** even do?)  in SomePrecedingMethod of the controller.  And the correct URL is being called by the browser.  BUT, the SomeNonIndexMethod method being routed to also needs the POST data from the SomePreceedingMethod method and / or from the view.  Anyway, currently I can route to the alias OR get the Post data without a Redirect.  Please do not cite redirect()->withInput() -- I've tried it, and seems to only work if you're trying to go BACK to a previous page / method.

An example of your solution would be most helpful.

Comment: What is your main question exactly?

Comment: What you call an alias is a URI fragment and in your CI4 code example this would be `SomeController/SomeNonIndexMethod`. What you did with `as => Net_Price` is giving the route a name internally which you can call from within your app (so when your url for this site would change you just have to change the `route.php` entry).

Comment: You know that you can do 100% the same in CI4 ... https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/routing.html#setting-routing-rules is this not what you're after? I get it - you want to be able to create a custom route (and auto loading routes is now discouragted in CI4) and that functionality still exists. Unless you mean something different??

Comment: @SimonWeber Yes. I realize that now. I tested it with a method that doesn't need to also get post, and I called it by the URI fragment (Net_Price) -- once it loaded, the web browser was again back at example.com/SomeController/SomeNonIndexMethod NOT the desired URL of example.com/Net_Price.

Answer (score 0):

@Antony was correct and his comment is the answer.

For clarification:  The CI3 code was actually `$route['Net_Price'] = 'SomeController/SomeNonIndexMethod';`  In reformatting that code for CI4 -- specifically adding the get, post, or match part -- I was getting confused, and my *actual* route-code was like `$routes->match(['get', 'post'], 'SomeController/SomeNonIndexMethod', 'SomeController::SomeNonIndexMethod', [as => 'Net_Price']`  Basically, I had gotten it into my head that in order to call the method in the route-code I had to use BOTH `SomeController/SomeNonIndexMethod` AND `SomeController::SomeNonIndexMethod` in each route.  When, in fact, the 'slashed-bit' can be anything you want it to be -- the 'double-colon'd-bit' (not used in CI3 routes) is the actual controller-method reference.

The correct CI4-formatted route is:
`$routes->match(['get', 'post'], 'Net_Price', 'SomeController::SomeNonIndexMethod');`

Finally, the 'slashed-bit' (whether it has a slash or not) is what the View needs to reference in CI4.

Comment: Glad you solved it. Btw don't use underscores in your urls as it hinders your SEO ranking (web crawlers don't like underscores in urls).